# How to make a fluid/liquid Air application using Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, resolution, mobile-application

What I need is take advantage of the all area of the screen, independent of user's screen proportions. 
By default, Air apps scales proportionately from the inside out. This would be great if we hadn't so different screens sizes and proportions in Android.

Angry Birds is a good example of what I call of fluid layout, it always scales/zooms the three layers(front, game and background layer) accordinly.

My app is mostly a inteface based game, the user must see some info and click on some buttons. I think I could base my scale primarily in the user screen's width, and use a scroll if needed. The problem is how do that.

Comment: Someone voted to close and didn't even commented what is wrong with my question...

Comment: Have You ever try flex ? If You looking for non-flex solution , check this http://turbosqel.pl/ExMinimalComps/simple/

Comment: I think maybe they're assuming you're using Flex, which, ass the name implies, offers liquid layout through percentages on things like width and height.

Comment: I'm not using Flex, as I didn't even used it on question tags. Just added "Flash" in title.

Comment: Close vote of 'not constructive' implies someone deemed this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.  Flash scaling and coordinate system is a huge topic - this would be improved by specifics.  Use a camera-based viewport; or if you're packaging AIR, use Flex.

Comment: @JasonSturges, I think I'm going to delete this question. But first I'd like to ask if you know any similar Q&A site, where discussion or suggestions questions aren't forbidden?

I really love this site, but I think some questions have not the obligation of having a only one answer

Comment: This question isn't forbidden - only one person recommended to close.  Hold on and you'll get some answers.

Comment: @JasonSturges, ok! But sometimes I really want to discuss ideas, and not only have a direct answer, if you another good site for that, I'd thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fluid / liquid / responsive layouts would likely imply a layout manager of some kind.

This functionality is built in to Flex.

Per Flash, and more specifically to what you've noted per requirements it sounds like some basic scaling and positioning is what you desire.

**Layers**

As you've noted, different layers will have different requirements per scaling:

- background
- game play
- interface / controls

Background and game play might be a single layer; however, you may want different constraints on the foreground user controls for readability and interaction.

**Setting up the stage**

If you want to control scaling, you should set:

```
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

This also assists with orientation change of mobile devices swapping between portrait and landscape.

Browsers can be resized; so, you need to listen for resize events:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));

function resizeHandler(event:Event=null):void
{
    /* scale code ... */
}
```

**Positioning**

Top and left positioning are always easy, because top-left is 0x0 coordinate.  Right and bottom require subtracting a `DisplayObject` width from stage.

Right align example:

```
mc.x = stage.stageWidth - mc.width;
```

Bottom align example:

```
mc.y = stage.stageHeight - mc.height;
```

Keeping something in the center of the stage:

```
mc.x = (stage.stageWidth * 0.5) - (mc.width * 0.5);
mc.y = (stage.stageHeight * 0.5) - (mc.height * 0.5);
```

**Scaling**

You need to determine what your constraint is to avoid blank / empty regions on the stage.

This can be implemented using a ratio variable:

```
var ratio:Number = 1.0;
```

Proportional scaling:

```
ratio = stage.stageWidth / gameMovieClip.width;
gameMovieClip.scaleX = ratio;
gameMovieClip.scaleY = ratio;
```

Stretch display object to fit stage:

```
gameMovieClip.scaleX = stage.stageWidth / gameMovieClip.width;
gameMovieClip.scaleY = stage.stageHeight / gameMovieClip.height;
```

Best fit algorithms require fitting the minimum constraint of your display object within a bounds.  There are libraries that can assist with this, such as [Greensock auto fit area](http://www.greensock.com/autofitarea/).

[image: auto-fit-area]

**Virtual Cameras**

Virtual cameras have been popular in Flash.  The concept is that you design your view then pan and zoom a camera to show a specific region.

[O'Reilly ActionScript for Non-Coders](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/javascript/2004/08/17/flashhacks.html?page=last)

[image: v-cam]

- [Example 1](http://www.oreillynet.com/javascript/2004/08/17/examples/3Dcam02.html)
- [Example 2](http://www.oreillynet.com/javascript/2004/08/17/examples/3dcam01.html)
- [Example 3](http://www.oreillynet.com/javascript/2004/08/17/examples/3Dcam03.html)

Virtual camera FLA example:

- http://bryanheisey.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/vcam_as3.fla

Virtual camera example:

- http://www.fluidanims.com/FAelite/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=3369
- http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/87/t647746-cam-virtual-cam-for-flash-mx-lower-level-intermediate/
- http://www.flashkit.com/movies/Components/Flash_V--_redesig-10378/index.php

Google "Flash virtual camera" or "Flash v-cam" for examples.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jason! Sure this is the best and complete answer I ever received here!